# ASP MVC - How can I change the base url of the request for Url.Content?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a request with the following url:
**foo.bar.com/do/something**

The "something" action of the "do" controller returns a view with an image that has the following url: **foo.bar.com/content/image.png** (generated by the helper **Url.Content**) - this is just an example, my actual page has a lot of images

I want to know what can I do in the action to change the behaviour of the **Url.Content** so that it generates my image url with the url **localhost/content/image.png**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably is not the best solution, but it may work for you:

You could write a extension such as the one below to achieve this:

```
    // Determine if gen localhost or the normal hostname
    public static bool IsUseLocalhost { get; set; }

    public static string ContentFullPath(this UrlHelper url
        , string virtualPath, string schema = "", string host = "")
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        Uri requestUrl = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema))
        {
            schema = requestUrl.Scheme;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(host))
        {
            if (IsUseLocalhost)
            {
                host = "localhost";
            }
            else
            {
                host = requestUrl.Authority;
            }
        }

        result = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
                               schema,
                               host,
                               VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(virtualPath));
        return result;
    }
```

In the Action you can set the static `IsUseLocalhost` to `true` to turn all gen url with localhost.

Then in the view use it as:

```
@Url.ContentFullPath("~/content/image.png")
```

---

If you want to set explicity host, then in the view use it as:

```
@Url.ContentFullPath("~/content/image.png", host: "localhost")
```